# Python: Using Map/Lambda instead of for loop

Tags: python

How can i use the below code with map and lambda function ?

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print "*" * i
```

How to achieve the same with map and lambda function

```
map(lambda x:print "*"*x ,range(1,11))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from __future__ import print_function
map(lambda x:print("*"*x) ,range(1,11))
```

this works in python 2.7

Comment: why does not this work map(lambda x:print "*"*x ,range(1,11))

Comment: in python 2 print is a statement.
In python 3 is a function.
lamdba cannot have statements, so you can do the trick above.
check here http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/

Answer (score 3):

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: "*"*x, range(1,11))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
print '\n'.join([str("*" * i) for i in range(1, 11)])
```

Just use list comprehension to join the lines together using a line-feed.

---

### Additional Notes

There is more than one way to skin a cat. In this scenario either solution will work. Python is optimized for list comprehension. Plus, the creator, Guido van Rossum, HATES maps, filters, and reduce functions...

Also, he does not like lambda... Case-in-point http://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php

> If Guido van Rossum, the author of the programming language Python, had got his will, this chapter would be missing in our tutorial. In his article from May 2005 "All Things Pythonic: The fate of reduce() in Python 3000", he gives his reasons for dropping lambda, map(), filter() and reduce(). He expected resistance from the Lisp and the scheme "folks". What he didn't anticipate was the rigidity of this opposition. Enough, that Guido van Rossum wrote hardly a year later: "After so many attempts to come up with an alternative for lambda, perhaps we should admit defeat. I've not had the time to follow the most recent rounds, but I propose that we keep lambda, so as to stop wasting everybody's talent and time on an impossible quest."
> We can see the result: lambda, map() and filter() are still part of core Python. Only reduce() had to go; it moved into the module functools.

TL;DR - Do not try to use a language as if it were another.

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat. In this scenario either solution will work. Python is optimized for list comprehension. Plus, the creator, Guido van Rossum, HATES maps, filters, and reduce functions...

Comment: A nit: The brackets are superfluous. `print '\n'.join(str("*" * i) for i in range(1, 11))` works fine.

Comment: yes but still you can do it with map. It is perfectly valid.
The others are a matter of taste

Answer (score 0):

use

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: "*"*x, range(1,11))))
```